# Unable to deploy business network after upgrading to composer v0.8.0

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I have a business network which has deployed no problem in the past, now when I try to deploy using the command

> composer network deploy -a test.bna -i PeerAdmin -s adminpw -p hlfv1

I get

```
Deploying business network from archive: test.bna
Business network definition:
Identifier: test@0.0.1
Description: Test Network

✖ Deploying business network definition. This may take a minute...

Error: error trying deploy. Error: Failed to deserialize creator 
identity, err MSP Org1MSP is unknown
Command failed
```

what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

This error could be the result of a problem to create the channel and join the peer to the channel. 
If you followed the hyperledger composer guides and downloaded the hyperledger fabric development server then you must ensure you have a version of docker equal or greater to **version 17.03**. The channel will fail to be created on older versions of docker.

Answer (score 0):

It seems also a problem related to the connection profile and the new changes on identities. Check https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/business-network/bnd-deploy.html and [Trying to deploy a business network onto hyperledger fabric 1.0 beta fails to install chaincode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44602202/trying-to-deploy-a-business-network-onto-hyperledger-fabric-1-0-beta-fails-to-in)