# Trying to deploy a business network onto hyperledger fabric 1.0 beta fails to install chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I have v0.8.0 of hyperledger composer installed and when I try to deploy the business network using the following command I get an install chaincode error

> composer network deploy -a test.bna -p hlfv1 -i admin -s adminpw

And the response is

> Error: error trying to deploy. Error: error trying install chaincode. Error

What is the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

The security model changed after hyperledger v1.0.0-alpha1. Now peers have the concept of Admin users. The userid 'admin' is a userid controlled and owned by the certificate authority server that is provided as part of the fabric composer development hyperledger fabric and has no authority on the Peer.

The Development fabric pre-loads the peer's Admin id into the KeyValStore defined by the profile 'hlfv1' and calls it PeerAdmin. This is the userid you must specify in order to deploy a business network onto the peer. 
As this user has already preloaded it doesn't have a secret but hyperledger composer currently requires a secret to be specified. It doesn't matter what you specify for the secret so long as you specify something. So the deploy command looks like

> composer network deploy -a test.bna -p hlfv1 -i PeerAdmin -s anything