# Authorization failure when creating new business network in local playground

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am trying follow the steps of Composer Playground tutorial for local version of the playground and using local fabric peer.

I have done prescribed sequence of steps: downloadFabric.sh, startFabric.sh, createPeerAdminCard.sh. Once I bring up the playground, I can see network card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 showing no business network attached to it.

Then I click on Deploy a New Business Network, and select "vehicles-lifecycle-network" example. The dialog looks similar to the one in tutorial, but it has additional fields asking for credentials for network administrator, and I am not sure what to put there.

I tried copying in key and certificate that were generated by createPeerAdminCard script, and I also tried using ID and Secret option putting in PeerAdmin or PeerAdmin@hlfv1. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44602202/trying-to-deploy-a-business-network-onto-hyperledger-fabric-1-0-beta-fails-to-in/44602204#44602204) answer which indicates that it does not matter what secret you specify as the user is already imported into the keystore -- not sure if it is relevant. It certainly did not make any difference.

When I click deploy, the new network seems to appear in the composer dashboard. However, if I click on "Connect Now", a popup shows "Error trying to login and get user context" and [[{"code":400,"message":"Authorization Failure"}]].

It seems I am missing something very basic, but cannot really figure it out on my own.

**Edit:**

Simple steps to reproduce (assuming basic-sample-network.bna is available locally):

```
> composer runtime install -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -n basic-sample-network
> composer network start -a <path to basic-sample-network.bna> -A admin -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -C <path to PeerAdmin certificate> -f admin.card
> composer card import -f admin.card
> composer network ping -c admin@basic-sample-network
```

Last command produces the same error as above in the console.

**Edit 2:**

If I open up ~/.composer/cards/PeerAdmin@hlfv1/metadata.json and add "businessNetwork":"basic-sample-network" parameter, I am able to do composer network ping -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 successfully, and also can connect to the network from the Playground -- this will do as a workaround for now. However, I must be doing something wrong with the way I create new network and its admin card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Playground Tutorial assumes that you are connecting to an Online Hosted Playground hosted on IBM Cloud (Bluemix).  For the Online Playground the underlying Fabric is 'Web' - i.e. the Fabric is stored only in the local browser.  This document may help explain the different Fabric Runtimes: [Typical Solution Architecture](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/introduction/solution-architecture.html)

The Local Playground gives you the additional option of deploying a Business Network to an hlfv1 Fabric, using the PeerAdmin card that you created with the `createPeerAdmin.sh` script.

After creating the PeerAdmin card you should be able to start Playground locally with the `composer-playground` command and you should be able to deploy a Business Network.  In this development scenario the **Credentials for the Network Administrator** should be **Id and Secret** specifying admin / adminpw. There is no need to run CLI commands prior to starting local playground. (createPeerAdminCard.sh is not a CLI command but is a Dev environment setup script - and it should be run.)

If you want to go down the CLI route please see the [Developer Tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/developer-tutorial.html)

Comment: Thanks! Using admin as ID and adminpw as Secret did the trick